# How can I return an $_SESSION as opposed to the value of the $_SESSION?

Tags: php, function, session

I ran into a small problem that was easily fixed, but got me thinking about the idea of returning a $_SESSION from a function as opposed to returning the **value** of the $_SESSION.  As an example, let's say I want to write a function to unset a $_SESSION (I know that the following example is silly, but I'm hoping to use it to illustrate a point).

```
function sessionFunction($name) {

return $_SESSION[$name];

}

$session_to_unset = sessionFunction('unset_me');
unset($session_to_unset);
```

The above won't work because I'm returning the **value** of the $_SESSION as opposed to returning the $_SESSION itself.

Of course, I could just do (again...very silly function, but used to illustrate a point):

```
function sesssionFunction($name) {

return $name;

}

$session_to_unset = sessionFunction('unset_me');
unset($_SESSION[$name]);
```

but, I'm wondering if there's a way to actually return the $_SESSION array as opposed to its populated value so that I can unset the returned value (as in the first example).

Comment: You can't use the first syntax `unset($whatever)` no matter what. That's just how PHP is. You could set up other possible syntactic patterns by tapping into magic functions, but `unset($whatever)` can *never* result in stuff being modified somewhere else.

Comment: You can do it by writing an appropriate class. Something like `$foo = $session->get('foo'); $foo->remove();` is possible, though arguably this can quickly get confusing (e.g. you removed foo, but still have its object around). In short, this is not really a pattern you should be using to begin with.

Comment: @Jon, this gets at the heart of my question.  As it looks like there's no "good" answer to this question, could you change your "comment" to an "answer", and I'll accept it?

Comment: @Eric: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do that will enable the straight `unset($var)` syntax. That's because there is no hook in PHP that lets you customize the behavior of `unset` -- there's the magic method `__unset`, but that only comes into play when called on object properties.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` is a "superglobal". From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php):

> This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.

There is no need to return it, as it is available in its correct form anywhere anyway.

Comment: I appreciate the comment!  And, I'm aware of the global nature of $_SESSIONS; my question, however, is more regarding the concept of returning the $_SESSION "thing" versus the value of the "thing"...